# how to add missing CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I want to get a base64 encoded image from another domain. I have enabled CORS on the backend but I am getting an error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://codedecoder.pythonanywhere.com/media/embed/2021/10/07/temp.jpg. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="datadiv"></img>
```

```js
var src = 'https://codedecoder.pythonanywhere.com/media/embed/2021/10/07/temp.jpg'

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: `https://codedecoder.pythonanywhere.com${src}`,
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function(dayta) {
    console.log(dayta);
    $('#datadiv')[0].src = dayta;
  },
})
```

Comment: That error means that you have not configured CORS correctly on the server. This is 100% a server-side problem. If CORS is configured correctly, you do not need to make any JS changes.

Comment: What about missing headers

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? If you're referring to the error, it means that the ***response*** coming back from the server is missing the necessary CORS headers.

Comment: yes. how do i add missing headers and where ?

Comment: You cannot add them on the frontend

Comment: As I mentioned, you need to add them server side. Your question states that `I have enabled CORS on the backend`, however if you're still seeing this error then it means that it hasn't saved the configuration, or you configured it incorrectly.

Comment: Why? then whats the solution?

Comment: I think cors is enable successfully as i am able to make other requests even post request

Comment: We can't tell you what's wrong when you haven't told us how you've configured CORS in the first place. The code in the question is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Do you know django?

Answer (score 1):

You set CORS headers on the server side. It's not a client side problem. But, for development purposes, you can use Chrome's CORS extension. Look it up on the chrome extension store.

Answer (score 0):

For Django, check out the django-cors-headers package:

https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers

It is maintained by a member of the Django Software Foundation technical team.